# Changing iFrame on dropdown click

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I'm new to programming and I'm trying out some stuff.
The thing is now im stuck at the moment, I'm making a webpage at the moment.
What I want to achieve at the moment is that if I click an item in the drop down menu it changes the iFrame source to the link I want. what am i doing wrong here?

```
 <div class="dropdown droplist">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
        aria-expanded="false">
        Choose List
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" id="#action-1">Party</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Furutre</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Late Night</a>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    jQuery("#action-1").click(function (e) {
        function switchView() {
            document.getElementById("spotifycontainer").src =
                'https://open.spotify.com/embed/user/21sbumll6xursi72kr7vkspay/playlist/4VEIFU2doL7TdnolXXFd70';
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
<div>
    <iframe src="" class="spotifylist" width="1280" height="720" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" id="spotifycontainer">
    </iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are trying to use jQuery without importing it. 
Always be sure to open the console to check for handy error messages.

You can use `onClick` in your html to call a JS function like this

```
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onClick="switchView('party')">Party</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onClick="switchView('future')">Furutre</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onClick="switchView('lateNight')">Late Night</a>
</div>
```

Then you can create a `switchView` method that looks like this

```
function switchView(mode){
    let spotifyContainer = document.getElementById("spotifycontainer");

    if (mode == 'party'){
    spotifyContainer.src='https://open.spotify.com/embed/user/21sbumll6xursi72kr7vkspay/playlist/4VEIFU2doL7TdnolXXFd70';
    }
    if (mode == 'future'){
    spotifyContainer.src = 'https://open.spotify.com/embed/user/21sbumll6xursi72kr7vkspay/playlist/4VEIFU2doL7TdnolXXFd70';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you with some trail and error I came to doing it this way as well. but thank you sir !!!